# CORS headers not working only in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, iis, http-status-code-503

I'm having problems only on Mozilla Firefox, my requests are "Unavailable (503)" because of the missing header Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

However, the header is on the server side, inside my web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
   <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
```

This is the error (translated from spanish):

Request from another blocked source: the same source policy: http: // XXXXX (reason: missing CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header).

The problem does not happen on IE and Chrome. Any clues?

Thank you all!

Comment: What do the actual HTTP response headers look like?

Comment: 503 is not a CORS failure.

Comment: please post the full response - you might want to check the iis logs

Comment: HTTP status codes and cross-origin related errors are unrelated. If you're get a 50x error, then you need to look at your server logs to find out what the error message actually is.

Comment: @DanielA.White I know, but that's the error I'm having. Edited answer. Thanks

Comment: Note that getting a 50x error will likely cause the CORS headers to not be sent *as a side effect* resulting in an access control error message on the client. You still need to look at the server logs and identify the underlying cause of the 50x error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, maybe this could help someone:

On the request uris I was using  the server name instead of the IP. IE and Chrome were able to resolve this, Mozilla wasn't.

I don't know how is this a problem for Mozilla anyway.

Thank you all